# Calling function and getting - not enough input arguments, even though syntax is correct

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, svm

I'm teaching myself classification, I read and understood the MatLab online help of the simple LDA classifier which uses the fisher iris dataset.

I have now moved to SVM. But even though I use the exact syntax from the help page I get an error of either not enough or too many input arguments.

I have made trained my SVMClassifier using `svmtrain` via the command:

```
SVMStruct = svmtrain(training,labels);
```

Where `training` is a 207 by 900 training matrix. There are 207 samples and 900 HoG descriptors or features. Similarly `labels` is a 207 by 1 column vector consisting of either `+1` or `-1` for their respective samples.

I then wanted to test it and see if this works by calling:

```
Group = svmclassify(SVMStruct,sample,'Showplot',true)
```

Where `sample` is a 2 by 900 matrix containing 2 test samples. I was expecting to get `+1` and `-1` as these are what the test samples should be labelled. But I get the error:

> Too many input arguments.

And when I use the command

```
Group = svmclassify(SVMStruct,sample)
```

I get the error

> Not enough input arguments.

Comment: you might have overloaded the function. try `which svmclassify` does it points to the right function? try also `doc svmclassify` and see what your version requires.

Comment: @Shai Thank you. That fixed it. ``which svmclassify`` was pointing to some mex svm I compiled earlier and forgot about. If you add this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have overloaded `svmclassify` function.
try

```
>> which svmclassify
```

to verify that you are actually calling the right function.

In case that you overloaded the function (that is, created a different function with the same name `svmclassify`) and it is located higher in your `path` then you'll need to rename the overloaded function and run `svmclassify` again.